# Pitch Adjustment Loose on Tripod

Tags: tripod

I have two separate tripods from different manufacturers. For whatever reason, the pitch adjustment is loose on both of them. This often causes the mounted camera or cellphone to fall way out of position during the capture session. In extreme cases, I've even seen this cause the current tripod to fall over with the capture device onboard... It's particularly problematic with bulky, heavy cameras.

There is a knob on both tripods that looks like it's supposed to tighten and set the pitch adjustment, but I can crank that baby down tight and yet the pitch adjustment still seems loose (See Picture of my best tripod).

[image]

Are *both* of my tripods defective? If so, is there a hack I can use to keep my tripods from losing the pitch adjustment in the middle of a capture session?

Comment: What model tripods? How old are they? Sure it's possible that the threads have stripped or that there is something jammed in the mechanism that prevents it from tightening. TBH, though, on my tripods, that knob stops rotation, while tightening the handle below the big text is what locks the pitch. Maybe you're just tightening the wrong knob?

Comment: "...tightening the handle below the big text..." is an answer. I think you should post it as such. The problem is that I didn't know how to use a tripod...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try tightening the long handle below the big text in your picture. That's the knob for pitch-lock.

The knob your arrow points at is for the pivot (or yaw) lock.

Also, the "correct" terms just hit me:

- "Pitch" -> Tilt
- "Pivot" -> Pan

Answer (score 2):

Different answer: I rarely use a tripod head. In most of my tripod uses, the camera is about horizontal. I have found that using a leveling base such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089FC8ZKX)(*) with the camera directly attached to it (or via a quick-release plate):

- makes the tripod lighter (and smaller)
- makes it easier to lock the camera in position

(*) First found on Amazon, not recommending any specific model